# How to stop a task deployed to the cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, scheduling, cloud-deploy

While trying to learn about cloud tasks, I evaluated

```
CloudDeploy[SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[Print[Now], Quantity[1, "Minutes"]]]]
```

It is now printing the result of evaluating Now in Mathematica's messages window. I can't figure out how to stop and remove the task. I think my big mistake was my failure to assign the task to an object so I can talk to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It prints to MMA's messages notebook because you didn't submit it to the cloud but to the local session. What your code does is that + it deploys returned `TaskObject[..]` to the cloud, which does not do anything.

So to find the task you are taking about just take a look at `ScheduledTasks[]` or remove all of them: `RemoveScheduledTask /@ ScheduledTasks[]`

To submit a task to the cloud you'd have to do:

```
CloudSubmit[ScheduledTask[...],...]
```

Be careful though because it will be hard to find that task unless you catch the result. It is because cloud tasks are not associated with particular session so you won't find them in `ScheduledTasks[]`. Additionally `CloudObjets[None, ScheduledTask]` which should return such tasks, does not work. :)